# Multiply Series with DataFrame where series.index == dataframe.columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Hi I have a very simple scenario which I don't know how to solve via a simple method.

I have the following dataframes:

```
In [30]: d = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], index=['A', 'B', 'C'])

In [31]: d
Out[31]: 
   0
A  1
B  2
C  3

In [32]: dd = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3], "B":[10,20,30], "C":[100, 200, 300]}, 
                           index=["A", "B", "C"])

In [33]: dd
Out[33]: 
   A   B    C
A  1  10  100
B  2  20  200
C  3  30  300
```

I now want to multiply every column in dd with the value for that index in d. Essentially I'm trying to find a vector operation for the following loop:

```
In [55]: for i in d.index:
    dd[i] *= d.ix[i][0]
   ....:     

In [56]: dd
Out[56]: 
   A   B    C
A  1  20  300
B  2  40  600
C  3  60  900
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could

```
In [173]: dd * d[0]
Out[173]:
   A   B    C
A  1  20  300
B  2  40  600
C  3  60  900

In [174]: dd *= d[0]

In [175]: dd
Out[175]:
   A   B    C
A  1  20  300
B  2  40  600
C  3  60  900
```

Or,

```
In [179]: dd.mul(d[0])
Out[179]:
   A   B    C
A  1  20  300
B  2  40  600
C  3  60  900
```